# Paypal Sandbox PDT FAIL Error: 4020

Tags: paypal, asp-classic

```
Dim authToken, txToken    
Dim query    
Dim objHttp
Dim sQuerystring
Dim sParts(), iParts(), aParts
Dim sResults(0, 0), sKey, sValue
Dim i, result
Dim firstName, lastName, itemName, mcGross, mcCurrency

authToken = "%Token From SandBox%"

txToken = Request.QueryString("tx")

query = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx=" & txToken & "&at=" & authToken

set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", False

objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objHttp.Send query

sQuerystring = objHttp.responseText
```

I am getting Error "FAIL Error: 4020". Please guide me what I am missing.

Comment: Tidied up code formatting and removed a lot of the white space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal sandbox PDT Fail 4020](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002062/paypal-sandbox-pdt-fail-4020)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because:

- LIVE account PDT token is used instead of Sandbox.
- Incorrect token(check for white spaces,spelling)

If you still face issues, you can submit a ticket to [MTS](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/)